# RSS Reader solution which removes duplicate items

Tags: rss, duplicate

I tried Google's RSS reader with a userscript, but it didnt' solve my problem.
Any client is fine, I just want to have a bunch of RSS feeds without duplicates.

Comment: Where are the duplicates coming from? Do you have multiple feeds with the same posts?

Comment: Yes. In my case, it would be multiple Soup.io user's feed.